# Laspy - Laszip & TypeError

Tags: lidar, lastools, laspy, laz, laszip

I'm having some issues with Laspy and reading in .laz files.
Previously I have had no problem with this, but it has stopped working.

Initially I had a problem with the following error message: "laspy.util.LaspyException: Laszip was not found on the system"

I eventually got rid of this error using the top comment from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500149/laspy-cannot-find-laszip-when-is-installed-from-source-laszip-is-in-path)** (although I already had the whole LAStools package so I don't understand why I needed to add it again).

However, this now throws up a new error with the following message(s):

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-025be98bbf71>", line 1, in <module>
    inFile2 = File('/path/to/data/file/myfile.laz', mode='r')

  File "/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/laspy/file.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.open()

  File "/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/laspy/file.py", line 75, in open
    self._reader = base.Reader(self.filename, mode=self._mode)

  File "/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/laspy/base.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.setup_read_write(vlrs,evlrs, read_only=True)

  File "/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/laspy/base.py", line 321, in setup_read_write
    self.data_provider.point_map()

  File "/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/laspy/base.py", line 176, in point_map
    count=self.manager.header.point_records_count)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'FakeMmap'
```

I can't seem to find any help on this.

Note that I am using Laspy v1.6.0.

Also note that I do not want to just use .las rather than .laz

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

There is some kind of a recession with the latest numpy. See https://github.com/laspy/laspy/issues/112#issuecomment-583180711 for details.